# Rancher: Can we deploy with zero down time

Tags: docker, rancher

My project is using Rancher for docker orchestration. I see that every time Rancher upgrades new image, I see a down-time depend on web framework. For example, java framework, the down time is so large: about 10-15 minutes.

My question is: can we make the down-time comes to zero or nearly zero rather than current situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you can upgrade when you say 'Rancher'.

The actual server (`rancher/server`) upgrade, the infrastructure stacks upgrade.

For a faster `rancher/server` upgrade, you can do a `docker pull rancher/server:vX.Y.Z` before the actual process.

The same strategy could be used on the nodes too.

We try to keep the base image same between different releases so that only the updated layers need to be fetched to reduce the image download time. And the upgrade time can increase depending on the number of nodes in the cluster.